# Is this "mov" command properly implemented from my text book?

Tags: assembly, pic24

I am currently solving some problems out of "Microcontrollers Second Edition" and the question is asking:
`mov [ W1],W0`
The initial register memory contents of

> W0 = 0x1004
>   W1 = 0x1006
>   W3 = 0xF0A2
>   0x1000 = 0x382A
>   0x1002 = 0xFB80
>   0x1004 = 0x80FF

The answer is:

> W0 = 0x80FF
>   W1 = 0x0804

once the command is executed. The problem I am facing is the fact that there is no operation before the [ W1] register such as "--" or "++" which is why I do not understand how they came to this answer. If anyone could clarify I would greatly appreciate it.

```
mov [ W1],W0 ;Intentional space left before "W1" register.
```

> W0 = 0x80FF
>   W1 = 0x0804

is the answer

Comment: What architecture is this?  Some custom example ISA for that textbook?  How does one `mov` instruction change both `W0` and `W1` to totally different values?  `++` or `--` wouldn't explain anything.  So yeah, could well be an error in the book.

Comment: That is exactly what I was thinking! From my past experience brackets around a register serve sorta like a pointer in C but the initial register or its memory contents do not get modified. In this book however, it says both register's memory contents are being modified leading me to believe is an error.

Comment: Yes, exactly.  `[reg + offset]` in x86, ARM and others, or `offset(reg)` in many RISC ISAs, just reference memory at that address without changing the register.  PowerPC and ARM have ways to update `reg` to `reg+offset`, but you're not using an offset.  Updating the pointer register based on the result loaded from memory would be *super* weird, and often less useful.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is a mistake in this book. 
The "[]" means the data saved at the address written in the register inside the brackets. The only data changed in the line above is [W1] neither W1 or W0 changed.

Comment: Some asm syntaxes are `mov src, dst` which would explain `W0` changing.

Comment: @PeterCordes yes that’s possible too